# MySQL Procedure Sub-query Join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have been trying to debug this code, and I am not sure what the issue is. Looking over plenty of examples the form and syntax is correct. What am I missing?

```
BEGIN 
   SELECT *
   FROM items 
   WHERE 
      FIND_IN_SET( i_Name, wordArray ) 
   OR 
      FIND_IN_SET( i_Desc, wordArray ) 
   OR 
      ( a_ID IN (
          SELECT it.a_ID 
          FROM item_tags AS it 
          LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON it.tag_ID = t.tag_ID
          WHERE t.tag_Title IN wordArray
      ) AND i_Name IN (
          SELECT it.i_Name
          FROM item_tags AS it 
          LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON it.tag_ID = t.tag_ID 
          WHERE t.tag_Title IN wordArray) 
      );
END
```

This is supposed to be a search procedure, which checks the items name and description as well as the tag table.
Tag_ID are both INT length 6, and wordArray is a VARCHAR length 255.
Item_tags has the primary keys from the item table and the primary key from the tag table.
The full error I am getting as shown by `Phpmyadmin` is as follows:
The following query has failed:

```
"CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `findItem`(IN `wordArray` VARCHAR(255)) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN SELECT * FROM items WHERE FIND_IN_SET( i_Name, wordArray ) OR FIND_IN_SET( i_Desc, wordArray ) OR ( a_ID IN ( SELECT it.a_ID FROM item_tags AS it LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON it.tag_ID = t.tag_ID WHERE t.tag_Title IN wordArray ) AND i_Name IN ( SELECT it.i_Name FROM item_tags AS it LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON it.tag_ID = t.tag_ID WHERE t.tag_Title IN wordArray) );; END"
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wordArray ) AND i_Name IN ( SELECT it.i_Name FROM i' at line 13
```

Comment: The first obvious thing is that MySQL does not support `full join`.

Comment: changed to left join after, checking the full join. still getting error though will update question.

Comment: You can't use a string with `IN` as if it were a list, `WHERE t.tag_Title IN wordArray`.  The syntax is `IN (val1,val2,val3,...,valn)` and the values must be individual variables or literal strings.  That's what `FIND_IN_SET()` is for... it accepts a string containing a comma-separated list as the second argument... but `FIND_IN_SET()` is not sargable.